# Nestle-Aland equivalent critical apparatus for early New Testament translations

Tags: textual-criticism, translation-philosophy, new-testament, tools-of-biblical-studies

As an amateur textual critic, I've become very interested in the early translations of the New Testament, and I found [this page](http://rosetta.reltech.org/TC/TC-versions-bib.html) listing a number of critical editions of NT translations.

At least in the case of the Coptic (either Sahidic or Bohairic), is there a newer critical apparatus (in the style of the Nestle-Aland text or the United Bible Society text) available for purchase? So far, I've only found reprints of the Horner work, which while a good starting place, is 11 volumes long between the [Sahidic](https://books.google.com/books?id=nKx0AgAAQBAJ&pg=PR3&lpg=PR3&dq) (7) and [Bohairic](https://archive.org/details/copticversionofn01hornuoft) (4) editions.

(At the very least, Amazon did not have a newer critical text, though it did have newer editions of the NT available by J. Warren Wells which were not critical texts.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in D.C. Parker's work *An Introduction to the New Testament Manuscripts and their Texts* he states in his section on the Coptic version that

> The most extensive edition of the Coptic remain those of George Horner, in two series, published between 1898 and 1924.

This was published in 2008, so unless someone knows of a more recent answer, I believe this answers my question.